# Is there a Has-Only-One constraint in NUnit?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

I'm finding myself needing a lot of this sort of logic lately:

```
Assert.That(collection.Items, Has.Member(expected_item));
Assert.That(collection.Items.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
```

I see that NUnit offers `Has.Some` and `Has.All`, but I don't see anything like `Has.One`.  What's the best way to accomplish this without two asserts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of NUnit 2.6 (not around when this question was asked):

```
Assert.That(collection.Items, Has.Exactly(1).EqualTo(expected_item));
```

`Has.Exactly` "Applies a constraint to each item in a collection, succeeding if the specified number of items succeed." [[1]](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.6.3)

Comment: I think this fails to check that the collection has exactly one item in total as well, as per the OP original code.

Comment: This assertion doesn't check, whether the total count of the collection is equals to one or not.

Answer (score 9):

You could try something like this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(collection.Items.Single(), expected_item);
```

Single will return the only item in the collection, or throw an exception if it doesn't contain exactly 1 item.

I'm not that familiar with NUnit though, so someone might offer a better solution that does use an NUnit function...

EDIT: after a quick search, the only NUnit function that seems to come close is `Is.EquivalentTo(IEnumerable)`:

```
Assert.That(collection.Items, Is.EquivalentTo(new List<object>() {expected_item}));
```

IMO the first option reads better to me, but the latter might give a better exception message depending on your preferences.

Comment: Good answer.  I do still wonder if there isn't a constraint hiding in there somewhere that does what I want, though.. it seems natural enough, no?

Comment: Well not really natural, as a list naturally contains any amount of items, and if you're expecting only one, it defeats the purpose of a list :)

Comment: @PostMan - It is perfectly natural and very common to expect exactly one item in a list (or, in general, an IEnumerable) for a _specific_ test scenario.

Comment: I prefer your edited answer because the first answer would not throw an AssertionException, which can be confusing IMO (looks like an unintended bug in the test code).

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to verify that there is only one item in the collection, **and** it verifies the condition is to do something like:

```
Assert.That(collection.Items, Has.Count.EqualTo(1).And.All.EqualTo(expected_item));
```

That's how you'd get the best error message in case of failure.
The second best way would be @BubbleWrap's edited answer, which does the assertion job but would get the same error whether your collection has more than one item or the item is not the expected one.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Assert.IsTrue(collection.Items.Count() == 1 && collection.Items.Contains(expected_item));
```

Why it is not suffice for you?

Comment: Because of the poor error message when the test fails. If the count was different from 1 _or_ the item wasn't found in the collection, the error message would simply be "Expected: true; But was: false" - useless for quickly seeing what went wrong.

Answer (score -2):

If Items property has an indexer you could use

```
Assert.AreEqual(collection.Items[0], expected);
```

Comment: Doesn't confirm that there is exactly one item